# In SQL Server, SQL Agent Jobs. REPLACE not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL select statement that populates a csv using the SQL Agent Jobs.
However I have recently come across an issue where I need to use the replace function within SQL SERVER to clean up some of the data.

```
SELECT  Replace(Name,',',';')as Name ,Date
FROM db.table
Order by Date
```

Blows up every time with the :
Must pass parameter number # and subsequent parameters as '@name = value'.
    After the form '@name = value' has been used, all subsequent parameters must be passed in the form '@name = value'. 
    [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 119).  The step failed.

```
Some Sample Name Data:
Smith, Bob
Julie Smith
Anne Smith,DR
```

Thanks for any pointers. 
Respectfully.

Comment: If you remove the replace it works fine?

Comment: Where does that query come from? Try using braces around `name`.

Comment: nickfinity - no, doesn't work.     shawnt00 - braces didn't work.

Comment: can you show some sample data from your table?

Comment: Is it possible that your target database has a stored procedure named `REPLACE` in it?

Comment: no replace sp in the db.